# What causes a flag to be "aged away"?

Tags: support, flags, aged-away

In my flagged post history, I noticed a section for "aged away" flags.

[image: Aged away flags]

What exactly are "aged away" flags? Does it just mean the flag was inactive for a while? If so, how long does a flag need to be inactive for it to age away?

Comment: Found the original answer almost immediately after posting this. Marked as duplicate and closed.